# Abnormal behaviour of IN clause in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle9i

I am using Oracle database 9iR2. My Query is not giving result. Pls check

```
select stdno 
from std 
where stdno in (select stdno from std_degree where code=243);

no rows selected

select stdno 
from std 
where  to_char(stdno) in (select to_char(stdno) from std_degree where code=243)

no rows selected
```

---

```
select stdno from std_degree where code=243;

Output is: 
10064927
10064930
10065571
```

Another query:

```
select stdno from std where stdno in (10064927,10064930,10065571);

Output is:
10064927
10064930
10065571
```

It works through INNER JOIN.

```
select stdno 
from std 
INNER JOIN std_degree 
  on std.stdno=std_degree.stdno 
 and std_degree.code=243;

Output is:

10064927
10064930
10065571
```

Someone pls clarify that why is IN clause not working correctly.

Note that the same SQL statement is working perfectly in the replica of the same database.